# Express, how to pass long url path to react router?

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, react-router

There is so much 3rd party stuff going on that I don't even know how to word the question exactly, but let me try and explain what I want to do:

My webapp is a react/redux/react-router/redux-router/webpack webapp, and I use an express server to solve the CORS issues of going directly from the client to a server on another domain.

Express is running on port 3000, webpack dev server on port 8080

This is my express setup (for all I know it's too complicated, but there are so many libs to learn when doing webdev that sometimes you just need stuff to work instead of spending 3 days investigating each lib):

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/')));

  var proxyRules = new HttpProxyRules({
      rules: {
        '.*/broker': 'https://SomeDomain.com/broker/', 
        '.*/api': 'https://api.AnotherDomain.com/'
      }
    });



  var bundle = require('./bundle.js');
  bundle();

  var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

  proxy.on('error', function(e) {

  });

  // Any requests to localhost:3000/dist is proxied
  // to webpack-dev-server
  app.get('/bundle.js', function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/dist',
        changeOrigin:true
    });
  });


  app.all('/dist/*', function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin:true
    });
  });

  app.get('/img/:name', function(request, response){
    const name = request.params.name
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/img/' + name));
  });

  app.get('/css/fonts/:name', function(request, response){
    const name = request.params.name
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/css/fonts/' + name));
  });

  app.get('/css/:name', function(request, response){
    const name = request.params.name
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/css/' + name));
  });


  app.all('*', function(req, res) {
     var target = proxyRules.match(req);
    if (target) {
       return proxy.web(req, res, {
         target: target
      });
    } else {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/index.html'));
    }
 })
```

In short: webpack compiles to the `dist` folder. I copy my static assets (images etc) to `dist/img`, `dist/css` etc.

Now I set up a bunch of rules in the above config:

- when it goes looking for static assets it returns those (img,css,font)
- if the urls match the rules in the proxy, it proxies the url to do server-server requests without CORS issues
- if it asks for the `bundle.js` file generated by webpack, it returns that file
- all `localhost:3000/dist` calls are remapped to port 8080 where the webpack dev server is running
- all the remaining stuff (*) returns index.html

the problem now is making sure the react routes work correctly (they use the relative path in the url).

In the current configuration it works perfectly if for instance I open urls such as `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` or `http://localhost:3000/location`, but if I try a url of the style `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/profile/user5` it seems to fall back to the * rule that wants to return `index.html`

How can I solve this so it passes the complete path to the client-side router?

This is the client-side config

```
export const routes = (
  <Route component={Application} name="application">
    <Route component={Home} path="/"/>
    <Route component={Login} path="/login"/>
    <Route component={requireAuthentication(Dashboard)} path="/dashboard"/>
    <Route component={requireAuthentication(Locations)} path="/locations"/>
    <Route component={requireAuthentication(EditLocationTemplate)} path="/locations/template/location"/>
    <Route component={NotFound} path="*" />
  </Route>
);
```

If you have any comments about the general setup of Express here I am fine with that. Still learning how to use all this, so I am sure this is far from an optimal config.

Thanks!

Comment: It should always be returning index.html, right? Can you post your client side route config?

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: Are you trying to do server side routing? That's the only time Express should need to interact with React Router (or React at all, really).

Comment: Sort of. I need server-side routing to access the web services that run on another domain. That's the only reason I introduced this Express server.

Comment: Why are you not use nested routes?

Comment: I don't want to write every possibility. Can't this be done with some wildcard?

Comment: When you request `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` do you want it to proxy to an API or load and render the react application? Similarly, what should happen when you request `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/profile/user5`?

Comment: According to [Route Matching](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md) documentation, you're trying to do something like `path="/dashboard(/**)"` or `path="/dashboard(/profile/:user)"`. I haven't test it.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detailed to what /dashboard/profile/user5 should do?

Comment: @uptownhr, Freyday: it should pass that entire path to the react router on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express routes will match in the order you create them, ultimately falling back to your last "catch all" route (`app.all('*')`).

As you haven't written any matches for routes such as `/dashboard/profile/user5` it is doing essentially as you have asked, and defaulting to the catch-all route.

If you want to handle these without too much effort, you could create a list of top level routes that have children, and match these accordingly:

```
    var routesWithChildren = [
      '/dashboard',
      '/locations'
    ];

    routesWithChildren.forEach(function (rootPath) {
        app.get(rootPath + '/*', function (req, res) {
          // Send or render whatever is appropriate here
          // You can use req.path to get the path that was requested
          // Eg: /dashboard/profile/user5
        });
    });
```

Comment: So what you are saying is, it is impossible to make a "catch all" for all subpaths for a given path? I need to specify each and everyone of them explicitly?

Comment: No, that is the opposite of what I'm saying. The code in my example "makes a catch all for all subpaths for a given path". It will match all subpaths of /dashboard. It will match all subpaths of /locations.

Comment: From what I tested, this will match `/dashboard/item1` but not `/dashboard/item1/item2/item3`

Comment: I think you tested wrong.  Try his code exactly, it has the `/*` which should match subfolders.

Comment: I think I have made some errors in my routing definitions. You are right. Maybe I should completely rephrase the question with my new findings. Might be better of deleting this and writing a new one.